# How to set window's icon in Perl to some .ico file on Windows 7?

Tags: perl, windows-7, 64-bit, icons, ico

I was using [TK::Icon](http://www.bribes.org/perl/tkicon.html) with Perl 5.8.3 32bit, but it's not supported with Perl 5.10.1 64bit. When I try to install it through ppm, I get:

> C:>ppm install http://www.bribes.org/perl/ppm/Tk-Icon.ppd
>
> ppm install failed: The PPD does not provide code to install for this
>   platform

Is there any other way to do it?

Comment: Ask author to release this module to CPAN.

Comment: Alexander: Your advice really helped! I asked J-L from bribes.org to build the module for Perl64bit and he did so :). Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Alexandr suggested, I asked  J-L from bribes.org to build the module for Perl64bit and he did so.

So now the icon can be set with TK::Icon also on Perl 64bit.

The ppm install command is:

> `ppm install http://www.bribes.org/perl/ppm64/Tk-Icon.ppd`